# Angular - Get every segment of route

Tags: angular

First let me apologize in advance, if this question has been asked before - I'm sure it has, but I have not been able to locate it. I'm probably not using the correct terminology, so if you find the answer anywhere, please let me know :)

I'm in a situation, where I need to collect all paths/parameters, but I haven't found any obvious solution in either ActivatedRoute or Router.

Let me explain myself with an example - The current URL in the application is: `/product/details/10`

Currently, I can get what I want by doing: `router.url.split('/')`, 
which will split the string in an array with 3 entries: `['product', 'details', '10']`

However, in some cases my route will include a param, so something like this:

`/product/search?text=chair`

In this case, I can then again do another split by '?', to get the param `text: chair`.

While this does work, it doesn't look very nice, and I was thinking that Angular must have a smarter way of achieving the same result.

Ideally, I would like to call some method that splits this up in an object similar to this:

```
{
 paths: ['product', 'search'],
 param: { name: 'text', value: 'chair' }
}
```

It is not necessary to have this exact structure or anything, but I hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve; A simple way to get every segment of the route, as well as any included parameters

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inject an instance of `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`, you can get the url segments, the params, and the query params.

To inject, just do the following:

```js
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {}
}
```

Say we have the route `product/details/:id`.

If we navigate to the url `/product/details/5?key=value`, we can extract the following info:

#### Segments

```js
ngOnInit() {
  const snapshot = this.route.snapshot;

  const segments = snapshot.url.map(x => x.path);

  console.log(segments);

  // [ "product", "details", "5" ]  
}
```

#### Params

```js
ngOnInit() {
  const paramMap = snapshot.paramMap;

  const paramValues = paramMap.keys.map(x => {
    return {
      key: x,
      value: paramMap.get(x)
    };
  });

  console.log(paramValues);

  // [ { key: "id", value: "1" } ]
}
```

#### Query params

```js
ngOnInit() {
  const queryParamMap = snapshot.queryParamMap;

  const queryParamValues = queryParamMap.keys.map(x => {
    return {
      key: x,
      value: queryParamMap.get(x)
    };
  });

  console.log(queryParamValues);

  // [ { key: "key", value: "value" } ]
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-template-rsi4se

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed reply! I tried it out, but I kept getting an empty array in my segments property :( I think it might be related to where I'm calling it from, not quite sure

Comment: Can you recreate in a stackblitz? You should only get an empty array on your default path: `/`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be not a complete answer but it should hopefully get you started.

Try:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  combineLatest(
    this.route.url.pipe(
        map(urls => urls.map(url => url.path))
    ),
    this.route.queryParams,
  ).subscribe(([paths, queryParams]) => {
    console.log(paths);
    console.log(queryParams);
    console.log({ paths, param: queryParams }); // => This should be what you are looking for
  });
}
```